# bootstrap table filter - how to add "No matching records found" row when no results?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I use the following code snippet http://jsfiddle.net/giorgitbs/52aK9/1/:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

(function ($) {

    $('#filter').keyup(function () {

       var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
       $('.searchable tr').hide();
       $('.searchable tr').filter(function () {
          return rex.test($(this).text());
       }).show();

  })

}(jQuery));
});
```

this works great. However how can I display a row containing the text "No matching records found" when there are no results instead of a blank table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do something like this. First I add a (hidden by default) row to the table to show no data. Then in the jQuery, check the number of rows visible. If it's 0, show the hidden row.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    (function ($) {

        $('#filter').keyup(function () {
            var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
            $('.searchable tr').hide();
            $('.searchable tr').filter(function () {
                return rex.test($(this).text());
            }).show();
            $('.no-data').hide();
            if($('.searchable tr:visible').length == 0)
            {
                $('.no-data').show();
            }

        })

    }(jQuery));

});
```

```css
.no-data {
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">Filter</span>

    <input id="filter" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type here...">
</div>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Default</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="searchable">
        <tr class="no-data">
            <td colspan="4">No data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>EUR</td>
            <td>EURO</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Active</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>GBP</td>
            <td>Pound</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Active</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>GEL</td>
            <td>Georgian Lari</td>
            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
            </td>
            <td>Active</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>USD</td>
            <td>US Dollar</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Active</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi David! Thank you so much - this works perfect and is exactly what I was looking for. I still need to adjust that the div is hidding again once the search is changed but this I can achieve alone. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

You can add the number of records found using code below in bootstrap:

```
<tr class="no-data">
    <td colspan="14">No data available in table</td>
</tr>
```

Here, `"14"` indicates the number of columns present in the header row.